# why ies light not emitting?

Tags: light, emission

Creating false ceiling. The circular light having the ies lights, Same material used to the rectangular light. Why there is no emission on the rectangular panel. I have check the rectangular panel are assign with the led material. Any suggestion or help why no emission. Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: Which Blender version do you use? (And why got this question 2 downvotes?) I've opened the file in Blender 2.91.2 and the rectangles look white like the round areas. Might be a bug?

Comment: @Blunder 2.91.2. no lights for me

Comment: That's strange. I've tried with Blender 2.9.0 on another PC (Win) and it looks fine to me: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LY3ex.gif (material preview top/bottom + render preview top/bottom)

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like the light is emitting light, but since it is completely flat against the ceiling, no rays go sideways. I recommend making the lights slightly spherical if they are not. If they are already spherical, check the normals of the ceiling.